# Действие по клику на элемент Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, html5-canvas

Я пытаюсь сделать плейбл, в котором пользователь кликает на врага и его персонаж начинает его бить. Проблема с кликом на canvas, никак не получается его реализовать. Нужно, чтобы при клике на определенную область, изображение персонажа поменялось на другое. Возможно ли это сделать и как? 
Вот имеющийся код

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canvasLeft = canvas.offsetLeft;
var canvasTop = canvas.offsetTop;

var pers1 = {x:350, y:630};
var pers2=[];
var dragon = {x:470, y:600};


var barimg = new Image();
barimg.src = "img/bar.png";

var hpRedimg = new Image();
hpRedimg.src = "img/hpRed.png";

var hpGreenimg = new Image();
hpGreenimg.src = "img/hpGreen.png";


var pers2img = new Image();
pers2img.src = "img/bandit-sp.png";

var pers1img = new Image();
pers1img.src = "img/bandit.png";

var dragonimg = new Image();
dragonimg.src = "img/dragon.png";

var fonimg = new Image();
fonimg.src = "img/bg.png";


fonimg.onload = function(){
   game();
}


function game() {

   update();
   render();
   requestAnimFrame(game);
}

function update() {

// здесь код клика
}


function render() {
context.drawImage(fonimg, 0, 0, 1000, 1000);
context.drawImage(barimg, 100, 30, 700, 70);
context.drawImage(pers1img, pers1.x, pers1.y, 100, 170);
context.drawImage(dragonimg, dragon.x, dragon.y, 300, 200);
context.drawImage(pers2img, 128*Math.floor(pers2.animx), 128*Math.floor(pers2.animy),128, 128, pers2.x, pers2.y, 100, 100 );
context.drawImage(hpGreenimg, pers1.x+20, pers1.y-20, 60, 10);
context.drawImage(hpRedimg, dragon.x+50, dragon.y-20, 60, 10);

}


function resizeGame() {
var gameArea = document.getElementById('gameArea');
var widthToHeight = 1 / 1;
var newWidth = window.innerWidth;
var newHeight = window.innerHeight;
var newWidthToHeight = newWidth / newHeight;

if (newWidthToHeight > widthToHeight) {
newWidth = newHeight * widthToHeight;
gameArea.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
gameArea.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
} else {
newHeight = newWidth / widthToHeight;
gameArea.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
gameArea.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
}

gameArea.style.marginTop = (-newHeight / 2) + 'px';
gameArea.style.marginLeft = (-newWidth / 2) + 'px';

var gameCanvas = document.getElementById('game');
gameCanvas.width = newWidth;
gameCanvas.height = newHeight;
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeGame, false);
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', resizeGame, false);

var requestAnimFrame = (function() {
return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
function(callback){
window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/20);
};
})();
```

```css
.gameArea {
  position: absolute;
  left:     50%;
  top:      50%;

}
.game{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="gameArea" class="gameArea">
  <canvas id="game" class="game"></canvas>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А Вы уверены, что `update()` надо вызывать при отрисовке каждого кадра? Я так полагаю, что он должен вызываться по клику, менять какие то данные, на основе которых делается следующий кадр. И какая проблема отследить позицию клика на холсте? В объекте события же есть координаты клика.

Comment: Я только начинаю в canvas разбираться, поэтому совсем не исключено, что в коде есть ошибки) Пыталась найти, как правильно отследить позицию клика, но так ни к чему и не пришла. Можете подсказать?

Comment: добавил ответ с примером кода

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const output = document.querySelector("#output");

const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50);

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.fillRect(100, 120, 80, 50);

canvas.addEventListener("click", e => {
  output.innerText = `Координаты клика: ${e.offsetX}, ${e.offsetY}. `;
  if(e.offsetX < 100 && e.offsetX > 50 && e.offsetY > 50 && e.offsetY < 100) {
    output.innerText += `Вы кликнули по красной фигуре!`;
    output.style.color = 'red';
  } else if(e.offsetX < 180 && e.offsetX > 100 && e.offsetY > 120 && e.offsetY < 170) {
    output.innerText += `Вы кликнули по зеленой фигуре!`;
    output.style.color = 'green';
  } else {
    output.style.color = 'black'; 
  }
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 10px solid blue;
}

#output {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="output">Кликай по холсту!</div>
<canvas id="canvas" width=200 height=200></canvas>
```

Запустите код и кликайте по холсту, чтобы посмотреть как это работает (результат выводится в верхнем блоке).

Это простой вариант отслеживания клика. Заметьте, я использую `offsetX` и `offsetY` - координаты относительно левого верхнего угла, без учета границ и отступов (поэтому при клике по синей границе координаты отрицательные), то есть эти координаты и есть координаты холста.

Подробнее о событии `MouseEvent` и доступных свойствах читайте [здесь.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)

Comment: спасибо, это очень помогло)

Comment: @KseniaKuznetsova пожалуйста. Тогда примите ответ, если проблема решена (поставить зеленую галочку надо под рейтингом).

Answer (score 1):

Насколько знаю на обычно канвасе без библиотек это тяжело сделать.

Вот как менять если использовать  [Raphael](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/):

```js
const paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('papercanvas'), 100, 100)
const images = [
 'http://s53.radikal.ru/i142/0909/b1/c3e1eb475a50.gif',
 'http://s53.radikal.ru/i142/0909/b1/c3e1eb475a50.gif'
]
const img = paper.image(images[0], 20, 20, 80, 80)

img.click(changeImageSource)


function changeImageSource() {
 let src
 this.state = !this.state
  
  if (this.state)
   src = 'http://s60.radikal.ru/i168/0909/3a/21117ba1e58d.gif'
  else
   src = 'http://s53.radikal.ru/i142/0909/b1/c3e1eb475a50.gif'
    
  this.attr('src', src)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.2.7/raphael.min.js"></script>
Нажмите на персонажа для переключения картинки
<div id="papercanvas"></div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, получилось)